# How to add tokens from strtok_r to an array in C?

Tags: c

I have some code that looks like so:

```
char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
char* readFile = malloc(size);
char* words;
char* test[size];
char* token;

    fread(readFile, sizeof(char), size, textFile);

    int k = 0;
    for (token = strtok_r(readFile, delimit, &words); 
         token != NULL; 
         token = strtok_r(NULL, delimit, &words)) {

//        token = strtok_r(NULL, delimit, &words);

        test[k] = token;
        k++;
        printf("\n%s", test[k]);
        printf("\n%s", token);
    }
```

And with the code above, the output looks like so:

```
(null)
is
(null)
for
(null)
the
(null)
use
(null)
of
(null)
anyone
(null)
anywhere
(null)
at
(null)
```

But when I try to add those tokens to an array, in this case char *test, I get a null output.
How do I add the tokens to an array so I can use them at a later point?

Thank you

Comment: Is that the actual output of your program? The code has two prints for each word yet your example output doesn't seem to show that. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then include expected output and actual output.

Comment: @kaylum Updated, thank you

Comment: `k++` That's your problem. You increment before printing. So you store in test[X] but then print test[X+1]